# Jacobian Matrix Computation Formula?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, optimization

Where can I find a good concise reference about how to compute Jacobian in a systematic way? By combining a set of rules?

Edit: I am looking for fast ways to compute the Jacobian matrix, not the Jacobian determinant. Like if $f(x)= Ax$ is a function $f: \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^m}$, the Jacobian is $A$. 
What rules to use to come up with that quikly?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. The Jacobian is defined as a determinant. Are you asking how to compute determinants?

Comment: What resources have you looked at/What do you currently know about the Jacobian? Is it an intuitive sense that is missing or are you having trouble generating the matrix and taking the determinant?

Comment: Examples from wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @user25004 I would be surprised if other method than finding partial derivatives exists.. but who knows.. I have found a tool for this operation https://www.symbolab.com/solver/partial-derivative-calculator

Comment: You want to read the matrix cookbook.